# Send dropzone along with other data from form without specifying every single input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, dropzone

I am using dropzone to send attachments in a form. My issue was that dropzone was its own form so I searched a bit and found how to use dropzone with an existing html form and send everything in one post request.

The issue is that the solution I have now needs me to specify every single input field there is in the form. Is there a way to just post the entire form in my js code?

I have a lot of input fields and it must be possible to just send the entire form with the attachments appended to it instead of appending every input field to the dropzone post.

JS:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {
    url: 'upload.php',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 5,
    maxFilesize: 1,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    init: function() {
        dzClosure = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.

        // for Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
        document.getElementById("submitschade").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            dzClosure.processQueue();
        });

        //send all the form data along with the files:
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
            //Example fields, not from my actual form:
            formData.append("firstname", jQuery("#firstname").val());
            formData.append("lastname", jQuery("#lastname").val());
        });
    }
}
```

My form:

```
<form class="" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/" method="post">
  <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">Datum & tijdstip schade</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">Locatie aanrijding</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">Andere materiele schade dan voertuig(en)</label>
          <select class="form-control">
              <option selected disabled>Maak keuze</option>
              <option>Nee</option>
              <option>Ja</option>
          </select>
      </div>
  </div>
  <h2 class="mb-3">Bestuurder</h2>
  <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">Voornaam</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">Achternaam</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">Straatnaam en huisnummer</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">Postcode</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">Woonplaats</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">Telefoonnummer</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">Rijbewijsnummer</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">Rijbewijs type</label>
          <br>
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">A</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="A">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">B</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="B">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">C</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="C">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">D</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="D">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">E</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="E">
      </div>
  </div>
  <h2 class="mb-3">Voertuig</h2>
  <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">Merk / Type</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="example-text-input" class="col-form-label formlabel">Kenteken</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
  </div>
  <h2 class="mb-3">Bijlages</h2>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone">
          <div class="fallback">
              <input name="file" type="file" multiple="multiple">
          </div>
          <div class="dz-message needsclick">
              <div class="mb-3">
                  <i class="display-4 text-muted mdi mdi-cloud-upload"></i>
              </div>
              <h4>Sleep je bestanden of klik hier om bestanden bij te voegen</h4>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center mt-3">
    <input type="submit" name="submitschade" id="submitschade" value="Schadeformulier verzenden">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is, in your code `input` tags need a name to be included in the post by Dropzone.

Comment: @derloopkat Yeah but if I give them names I still have to specify them all right with the code as it is currently. Is there a line of code to get all input fields or serialize them or something along with the attachments?